# Array only renders when the code is saved - ReactJs + Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rendering

The component LatestChat receives a function to get the chat data from Firebase and an array of data from a hook called useChatFunctions.

**The problem is:** latestsChatsList only renders when I save the code. Even if I don't make any modifications, the array only renders when I save the code. Initially, I didn't want to set the latestsChatsList; instead, I wanted to use latestsChats in the component to render the `<li>` elements. However, it doesn't render, and I see the following console.log output:

[console.log in latestsChats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3NBu.png)

**But when I save the code, latestsChats can be seen like this in console.log**

[console.log in latestsChats the code is saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFkf.png)

When I save the code, latestsChats renders on the page and its console shows the red square. However, in less than a second, the `<li>` elements rendered by latestsChats disappear, and the console.log output changes to the blue square.

Does anyone have any ideas about this problem? It was working fine when the fetchLatestsChats only used the onSnapshot method to retrieve the chat collection from Firebase. However, I need to merge the contact information with this data using another query in Firebase.

So, basically, the code only works when I save it. If I refresh the page, the code doesn't work. But if I save the code, even without making any changes, it works.

Here's the hook (I omitted parts unrelated to the problem because there are other functions involved):

```
export const useChatFunctions = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [chatId, setChatId] = useState("");
  const [loadingMessage, setLoadingMessage] = useState(undefined);
  const [contactName, setContactName] = useState("");
  const [latestsChats, setLatestsChats] = useState([]);

  const fetchLatestChats = async (userId) => {

      const q = query(
        collection(db, "chat"),
        where("arrayUsersId", "array-contains", userId)
      );
    
      const getChats = onSnapshot(q, async (querySnapShot) => {
        let tempLatestChats = [];
    
        querySnapShot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          const chatData = doc.data();
          const otherUserId = chatData.arrayUsersId.find(id => id !== userId);
          let contactInfo = await getContactInfo(otherUserId);
    
          const chatWithContact = {
            ...chatData,
            contactInfo,
            otherUserId
          };
          
          tempLatestChats.push(chatWithContact);
        });
        setLatestsChats(tempLatestChats);
      });

  };
  
  const getContactInfo = async (userId) => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "user"), where("userId", "==", userId));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      const userDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
      return userDoc.data();
    } else {
      return "Nome do Contato Desconhecido";
    }
  };

  return {
    fetchChat,
    fetchLatestChats,
    sendMessage,
    messages,
    chatId,
    contactName,
    latestsChats,
  };
};
```

Here's the component LatestChat code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useChatFunctions } from "../../hooks/useChatFunctions";
import styles from "./LatestChat.module.css";

const LatestChat = ({ userId, setContactId }) => {
  const { fetchLatestChats, latestsChats } = useChatFunctions();
  const [latestsChatsList, setLatestsChatsList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLatestChats(userId);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLatestsChatsList(latestsChats);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ul className={styles.chats_list}>
        {latestsChats &&
          latestsChats.map((chat, i) => (
            <li key={i} onClick={() => setContactId(chat.otherUserId)}>
              <div className={styles.profilePicture}>
                <img src={chat.contactInfo.profilePictureUrl} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.messages_info}>
                <p className={styles.contact_name}>
                  {chat.contactInfo.displayName}
                </p>
                <p className={styles.last_message}>
                  {chat.messages[chat.messages.length - 1].message}
                </p>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default LatestChat;
```

Please, i need your help.

I created the following state to receive latestsChats, but it still only works when the code is saved.

`const [latestsChatsList, setLatestsChatsList] = useState([]);`

I expect that the code works the same way it does when it is saved, but without needing to save it, obviously. In other words, I want it to work continuously, even if the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `userId` to `useEffect` dependency list in `LatestChat`, so, instead of

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchLatestChats(userId);
}, []);
```

it should be

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchLatestChats(userId);
}, [userId]);
```

Without `userId` in deps list `fetchLatestChats` is called only on the first render of `LatestChat` when `userId` seems to be `undefined` and never again. It works when you save your code because component re-renders on save (but already with defined `userId`).

After fixes you can remove

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLatestsChatsList(latestsChats);
}, []);
```

and

```
const [latestsChatsList, setLatestsChatsList] = useState([]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work because userId isn't undefined ate the first rendering because i pass it as a prop from the parent component, add userId to dependency array results in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFkf.png. You can see the parent component here: https://i.imgur.com/vODlK6q.png